# CRM Upsert except if modified by non integration user

Tags: upsert, except

Is there a way to not update a record if it's been modified by a regular user?

Tried Adding a join to the user table with a unique Id is null because I am trying to update all records that are svc accounts and not any that were modified by a user those win but I still want a insert to occur if record is not already there.

I'm using Kingswaysoft SSIS With SQL 2016.  I've staged data from our V8 CRM and want to Upsert to v9 but don't want to overwrite any manual changes.